# Shell Script to run on Local and Remote machine

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am new to shell scripting,
I am trying to write a script that'll run on my local machine.

Few of it's commands are to run on my local and
 then a few on the remote server.

**Below is a sample script -**
The 1st two will run on my local system,
rest of them are to run on the remote server.

eg -

```
scp -i permissions.pem someJar.jar ubuntu@ip:/var/tmp
ssh -i permissions.pem ubuntu@ip
sudo su
service someService stop
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/someJar.jar
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/loggingFile.log
mv /var/tmp/someJar.jar .
service someService start
```

As the script will run on my local machine,
How do make sure the 3rd and further commands take effect on the remote server and not on my machine?

Here's my sample.sh file -

```
scp -i permissions.pem someJar.jar ubuntu@ip:/var/tmp
SCRIPT="sudo su; ps aux | grep java; service someService stop; ps aux | grep java; service someService start; ps aux | grep java;"
ssh -i permissions.pem ubuntu@ip $SCRIPT
```

The scp is working, nothing is displayed after that.

Comment: Pack them in a script, copy it to the remote machine just like you copy `some.jar`, and run it there via `ssh`

Comment: I wanted to avoid two scripts, no other way to achieve it in one?

Comment: You can try what Dmitri says below. Just remember to put your commands requiring `sudo` together like `sudo 'command1; command2; command3'`

Comment: @GMichael can you check the script I've added at the question's end, the scp is working but, nothing further gets displayed.

Comment: I could not try exactly what you have. But the following commands worked for me: `SCRIPT="sudo bash -c '/usr/bin/ps aux | grep java; '"` ; `ssh localhost $SCRIPT` . Try using SCRIPT like I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the reset of the script as a parameter to SSH. Try this format:

```
SCRIPT="sudo su; command1; command2; command3;"
ssh -i permissions.pem ubuntu@ip $SCRIPT
```

See: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:**
The reason why you don't see anything after running the command is because sudo expects the password. To avoid this there are three solutions:

1. Give `ubuntu` user needed permissions to perform all the tasks in the script.
2. Pass the password to sudo under SCRIPT: `echo 'password' | sudo su; ...`
3. Modify sudo-er file and allow `ubuntu` user to `sudo` without prompting for password. Run `sudo visudo` and add the following line: `ubuntu ALL = NOPASSWD : ALL`

Each system admin will have a different approach to this problem. I think everyone will agree that `option 2` is the least secure. The reset is up to debate. In my opinion `option 3` is slightly more secure. Yet, entire server is compromised if your key is compromised. The most secure is `option 1`. While it is painful to assign individual permissions, by doing so you are limiting your  exposure to assigned permissions in case if your key is compromised.

***One more note:*** It might be beneficial to replace `;` with `&&` in the `SCRIPT`. By doing so you will ensure that second command will run only if the first one finished successfully, third will run only if second finished successfully and so on.

Comment: so the SCRIPT you send as parameter will run automatically after the ssh command completes?

Comment: if all my commands are to run with sudo privileges, will it be like - SCRIPT="sudo su; ps aux | grep java; service linear stop; ps aux | grep java;" or something else?

Comment: I've updated the question, the scp is working, but nothing gets displayed after that.

Comment: I think the reason why you see nothing is because `sudo su`. Try adding running some basic command first, like `ls -la`. If you see output you give user ubuntu permissions to perform all tasks that you plan to do in that script.